# How do I increase UDP Recv-Q

Tags: linux, performance-tuning, udp

I have a gigabit connection that is not fully utilized but I am getting packet receiving loss.

When I do netstat, it shows the Recv-Q sometimes maxes out at 262656 during heavy traffic.

```
Proto Recv-Q
udp   262656
```

I've tried increasing these settings and rebooting my application but it doesn't seem to do anything.

```
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_default=4194304
sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_default=4194304
sudo sysctl -w net.core.rmem_max=16777216
sudo sysctl -w net.core.wmem_max=16777216
```

How do I increase the Recv-Q?

Answer (score 2):

Since Kernel 2.6.25 you have:

```
net.ipv4.udp_mem
net.ipv4.udp_rmem_min
net.ipv4.udp_wmem_min
```

`man 7 udp` has details